# Why we use ObservableCollection<T> in UWP/C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, uwp-xaml

I want to ask you why we use ObservableCollection Class in Our UWP app?

If we do not use ObservableCollection class what happen with our program?

Comment: ObservableCollection notifies when collection is changed. Great for updating stuff in GUI.

Comment: What do you mean why we use ? Be specific about matter OR read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx . You can google it.

Comment: I want to know main purpose of using ObservableCollection class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of `ObservableCollection` as opposed to classic collections like `List` is when you are using data binding with list controls. `ObservableCollection` implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and notifies the binding about any change that occurs in the collection.

The `CollectionChanged` event handler, and specifically the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` instance provides can inform about all types of item operations - replace, move, add and remove, so the list control can react as expected in each of these situations - like `ListView` which can show smooth animations for all of these events.

Any collection which does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` will still work with all list controls, but will only bind and load the items that are in the collection at the time of binding and any future changes will not be reflected in the control.